# Express redirection with header

Tags: node.js, express, http

I've created a simple express app to test redirection of headers.

Unfortunately, the header get dismissed after redirection.

When I request `/justheader2` using postman with some `X-Header` it works.

I hope someone could figure it out.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find any workaround to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A `redirection` in the `HTTP protocol` **doesn't** support adding any headers to the target location. It's basically just a header in itself and only allows for a URL.

When you adding your `X-Header` header with `res.header` you are sending that header back to the **client**.